# JAVA+POI API Excel- Need to increase width of the column

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to increase the width of the column of excel sheet. as the i am writing trough code is long.
and I need to drag the column manually to see the full text.

I did this –

```
HSSFRow dataRow = sampleDataSheet.createRow(0);

HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = setHeaderStyle(sampleWorkbook);

cellStyle.setWrapText(true);

***sampleDataSheet.autoSizeColumn(1000000);***
```

But its not changing anything..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work. However,

```
sampleDataSheet.autoSizeColumn(1000000);
```

auto-expands column 1000000.

If you want to auto-expand column 0(the first column), use:

```
sampleDataSheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

To auto-expand column 0 to 9(the first 10 columns):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
   sampleDataSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

Also, you should create all your rows and fill them with content first, before you call autoSizeColumn(so the column gets the width of the value with the broadest width).

(If you want to set the column width to a fixed value, use HSSFSheet.setColumnWidth(int,int) instead.)

Comment: hi-- I m doing like this                                      static HSSFSheet sampleDataSheet = sampleWorkbook.createSheet("ABC");                                      sampleDataSheet.setColumnWidth(20,20);       but I m not getting the  setColumnWidth methiod in the API.. pls see..

Comment: sampleDataSheet.autoSizeColumn(0);  worked for me on 1st column thanks soo much,+1 but cud u pls suggest me for my sampleDataSheet.setColumnWidth(20,20);  query...

Answer (score 14):

```
// We can set column width for each cell in the sheet        
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 1000);
sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 7500);
sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 7500);

// By applying style for cells we can see the total text in the cell for specified width
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle );
cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` works. this will resize the column to the largest cell length.

Comment: It only consider the width of the header not the content of the other cell of the column.

Comment: @Naveen This is incorrect -- `autoSizeColumn` should adjust the column width to fit all row contents.